# In unity, asmdef cannot refer Assembly-CSharp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope unity build ignore my test script, I i add following:

/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/Anti.Neighbor.Noise/Assets/Test/Test.asmdef

{
    "name": "Test",
    "references": ["Assembly-CSharp"],
    "optionalUnityReferences": ["TestAssemblies"]
}

unity editor console raise:

```
Assembly has reference to non-existent assembly 'Assembly-CSharp' (Assets/Test/Test.asmdef)
```

if i don't refer Assembly-CSharp, test script cannot import class in Aseebmly-CSharp
of course I can don't use asmdef file, but in this case, when unity building, building will include test script and raise "NUnit" dll not found err

so I hope a way to refer Assembly-CSharp to test my script

Answer (score 0):

Create another asmdef for the code that currently is in Assembly-CSharp (the default assembly).  You can then refer to the new assembly from the Test assembly.